# PHP: Get current date in EST timezone considering DayLightSaving Time

Tags: php

I have tried this code to get the current date in EST timezone,

```
$currentDate=date("Y-m-d h:i A");
$timezone='EST';
date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
$storedate=date("Y-m-d h:i A");
echo $currentDate."  ===  ".$storedate."<br/><br/>";
```

the storedate displays 1 hr late datetime. I think this is because of the daylight saving time.
Please provide me the best way to get current date in EST timezone considering Daylight saving time.